# Ошибка в sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite3

Почему выдает ошибку? 
`Ошибка:` `"sqlite3.OperationalError: near "table": syntax error"`

### Код

```
def sqlLiteConnect(self, db, table, column_name, lang=None):
    self.connect = sqlite3.connect(db)
    self.cursor = self.connect.cursor()
    self.query_columns = "PRAGMA table_info('+table+')"
    self.cursor.execute(self.query_columns)

    self.queryRow = """SELECT id, Word, Translation FROM table  WHERE id=random.randomint(0, 2000) """
    self.cursor.execute(self.queryRow)
    print(self.queryRow)
    self.cursor.commit()


sqlLiteConnect(self, 'db/Lings_Words_Db.db', 'generalWords', 'Word')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Первая ошибка, в этой строке:

```
self.query_columns = "PRAGMA table_info('+table+')"
```

по логике должно подставляться значение переменной table, но для этого нужно чтобы кавычки были одинаковые:

```
self.query_columns = "PRAGMA table_info(" + table + ")"
```

Т.е. должны соединяться три строки: `"PRAGMA table_info("`, строка из переменной table и `")"`, а у вас просто одна цельная строка, в которой table - это просто текст, а не имя переменной. Пробелы до и после + не играют роли, я их добавил для лучшей читаемости. Также, если нужно чтобы имя таблицы в итоговой строке было обернуто в одинарные кавычки, то нужно делать так:

```
self.query_columns = "PRAGMA table_info('" + table + "')"
```

Вторая ошибка: в SQL запрос вы добавили python код `random.randomint(0, 2000)` - но SQL этот код не сможет выполнить. Нужно получить случайное число средствами python, потом передать его в запрос:

```
self.queryRow = """SELECT id, Word, Translation FROM table  WHERE id=?"""
self.cursor.execute(self.queryRow, (random.randomint(0, 2000),))
```

См. справку по методу [execute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute).

Третья ошибка: в запросе `"""SELECT id, Word, Translation FROM table  WHERE id=?"""` table - это просто текст, который будет воспринят как имя таблицы (таблицы с именем `table`), а не имя переменной, вместо которой подставится значение аргумента метода.

Полный исправленный код метода:

```
def sqlLiteConnect(self, db, table, column_name, lang=None):
    self.connect = sqlite3.connect(db)
    self.cursor = self.connect.cursor()
    self.query_columns = f"PRAGMA table_info('{table}')"
    self.cursor.execute(self.query_columns)

    self.queryRow = f"""SELECT id, Word, Translation FROM {table} WHERE id=?"""
    self.cursor.execute(self.queryRow, (random.randomint(0, 2000),))
    print(self.queryRow)
    self.cursor.commit()
```

Обратите внимание: я использовал f-строки для подстановки значений переменных внутрь строк запроса. Подробнее можно почитать, например, здесь: [Форматирование в Python с помощью f-строк](https://pythonru.com/osnovy/formatirovanie-v-python-s-pomoshhju-f-strok)

Comment: Выполняю этот код, та же ошибка остается

Comment: @Injustive, дополнил ответ, смотрите с начала ответа.

Comment: И еще раз дополнил ответ

Comment: Скопировал ваш код, теперь ошибка
File "main.py", line 119, in sqlLiteConnect
    self.cursor.execute(self.queryRow, random.randint(0, 2000))
ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type

Comment: Поправил, там должен кортеж или словарь с параметрами передаваться.

Comment: А как мне теперь вывести эти значения? Просто когда выполняется команда print(self.queryRow) - выводит SELECT id, Word, Translation FROM generalWords WHERE id=?, просто присвоенную строку

Comment: Через `self.cursor.fetchone()`, если нужна только одна строка результата или `self.cursor.fetchall()`, если все строки, или через `for row in self.cursor`, если нужно пройти последовательно по строкам результата.

Comment: Все, спасибо вам огромное!